# Положение дочернего окна

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Какая функция вернет положение управляющего элемента `RECT{50,30,300,80}`?

```
HWND staticField = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, TEXT("STATIC"), nullptr, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER | SS_CENTERIMAGE, 50, 30, 250, 50, window, nullptr, GetModuleHandle(nullptr), nullptr);

RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(staticField,&rect) и GetClientRect(staticField,&rect) не подходят.
```

Comment: GetWindowRect чем не подходит? Судя по MSDN она должна вернуть именно координаты углов окна.

Comment: GetWindorRect записывает  в Rect {top=60 bottom=110 left=58 right=308} , немного не совпадает

Comment: Поясните сразу в вопросе какие вам координаты в итоге нужны: абсолютные или относительное (относительно окна-родителя).

Comment: нужны координаты относительно клиентской области окна родителя

Comment: А нет ли в окне какой "сетки", к которой привязывается дочернее окно? Попробуйте при создании указать те же "неправильные" координаты, что вы получаете через GetWindorRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> нужны координаты относительно клиентской области окна родителя

```
RECT rw;

GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rw);  
MapWindowPoints(HWND_DESKTOP, GetParent(hwnd), (POINT*)&rw, 2);
```

Здесь `rw` будет в клиентских координатах родителя.